# Errors on build creating a UWP cppwinrt SolidColorBrush

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

When creating a solid brush (cppwinrt) for a textblock I get errors when building, using:

```cpp
void MainPage::myStyle(Controls::TextBlock & block)
{   
    block.FontSize(72.0);
    block.Foreground(Media::SolidColorBrush(Windows::UI::Colors::Orange()));
    block.VerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment::Center);     
}
```

> error: LNK2019    unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::SolidColorBrush::SolidColorBrush(struct winrt::Windows::UI::Color const &)"

The error goes when I take the solidbrush out and I've also tried other versions of the solidbrush with the same error.

Answer (score 6):

You need to

```cpp
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.h>
```

to use types from namespace `winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Media`. This is documented under [Get started with C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/get-started):

> Whenever you want to use a type from a Windows namespaces, include the corresponding C++/WinRT Windows namespace header file, as shown. The corresponding header is the one with the same name as the type's namespace. For example, to use the C++/WinRT projection for the [Windows::Foundation::Collections::PropertySet](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.foundation.collections.propertyset) runtime class, `#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>`.